# How to instruct a beginner to regedit.exe?

Tags: documentation, regedit

i'm putting together some directions for beginners on how to check something in the registry. The first step is to get them to run **regedit**.

For a **Windows Vista** or **Windows 7** machine, what would be your directions on how to run regedit.

i'll get us started:

1. Click ...

Comment: If in the end your goal is to change (or delete) things in the registry, then I assume you know that double-clicking some `.reg` file might be easier? (Or, to dump some settings, `reg.exe` might be saver than `regedit.exe`, especially if you provide some batch file to do it.)

Comment: How do you access regedit?

Comment: @Arjan: You can suggest that, now you have to come up with instructions on how to run the batch file. But be warned that anything "runnable" will have to be vetted by their IT department first. (and their IT department are the people i'm writing the instructions for)

Comment: Are you asking me, Stevoni? i do Ctrl+Esc, regedit, Enter.

Comment: So you are saying the people in the IT department are numbnuts? (Still then, double-clicking a batch file seems easier than searching something in the registry, but it's your call.)

Comment: In this case i want to check that a Microsoft COM class is properly installed and registered - so i'd be dumping keys. You're free to come up with the steps that can dump HKCR\msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0\CLSID, and how to get the results into an e-mail.

Comment: They were trying to send us an error getting through SQL-QA. They literally typed out the error into an e-mail, rather than copy-paste.

Comment: Someone that has trouble running regedit, should not be using regedit.  This approach will just cause you more problems.   Use a .reg file or a script, or make an little app for them to change whatever it is.

Comment: I guess VBScript or whatever could fetch it, and create a new email message. But: can you be sure that computer has an email client set up? Maybe have the VBScript email it as well then? But: can you be sure there's no firewall blocking that?

Comment: Looking over reg, i'm sure i can come up with a cmd file, that they must "place on your desktop" that can generate five or six files with the various bits of keys i need. i can't say if .cmd files are blocked by their corporate firewall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold <kbd>The Windows Key</kbd> and hit <kbd>R</kbd>

Now type "regedit"

Now hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Bam, it's open. Take care.

This has worked since Windows 95 (maybe earlier, can't recall), and will almost certainly continue to work until the registry is abandoned.

Comment: How did you make those keys? :)

Comment: (And how do those keys look on Windows...? On my Mac they're too ugly to tell Emthigious the secret...)

Comment: Like this: <kbd>The Windows Key</kbd>

Comment: They look good in LinuxMint>Firefox.

Comment: This is what I find ugly on my Mac... http://img.skitch.com/20091029-bc4r6r2gf27fh5s3bg8x3kt267.png

Comment: It looks equally ugly on Windows, Arjan.

Comment: I think they look good. :)

Comment: I think they're a bit odd, but they get the point across, so I use them :)

Comment: I've never seen a keyboard that has "The Windows Key" printed on the spacebar. But if I hold down the spacebar and hit R, I get `"     r"` ;-)

Comment: You have a weird computer, Arjan, every PC I've ever seen has that on the Windows bar!

Comment: I use this way too.

Answer (score 0):

Start->Run->regedit.exe or Start->Run->regedt32.exe

'Numb nuts' shouldn't be given this command.  The registry tools don't have any Save or Cancel buttons.  Any change, accidentally or not, is immediate.  There is no Undo.  This is very dangerous.

Comment: Windows Vista and 7 do not have a **Start**, nor do they have a **Run**.